# Deleting previous .mxd project using arcpy

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, mxd, windowserror

I'm incorporating an already existing shapefile into a .mxd project. For this, I already created a .mxd and then saved a copy. The problem is that when I want to delete the old project (mxd) it tells me that it is in use (probably, since the second one is based on the first one).

How can I close the first .mxd project and then delete it?

Below is the code:

```
import os
import arcpy
import webbrowser as wb

mxdold = r"C:\Test\MAPTEST_2.mxd"
mxdcurrent = r"C:\Test\MAPTEST.mxd"

mxd = arcpy.mapping.MapDocument(mxdold)
df = arcpy.mapping.ListDataFrames(mxd)[0]

testfile = r"C:\Test\Testfile.shp"
arcpy.MakeFeatureLayer_management(testfile,"RECTANGLE")
layer = arcpy.mapping.Layer("RECTANGLE")
arcpy.mapping.AddLayer(df,layer,"AUTO_ARRANGE")

mxd.saveACopy(mxdcurrent)
wb.open_new(mxdcurrent)

os.remove(mxdold)
```

The error is the following:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:/Test/test.py", line 19, in 
os.remove(mxdold)
WindowsError: [Error 32] The process does not have access to the file because it is being used by another process: 'C:\Test\MAPTEST_2.mxd'

.

Comment: right before you `os.remove` try doing a `del mxd` -- the arcpy reference might be hanging onto it, thus not allowing you to use the os.remove. Otherwise you can call `arcpy.Delete_management` (GP tool to handle it)

Comment: With arcpy.Delete_management I get the error: "ERROR 000601: Cannot delete C:\Test\MAPTEST_2.mxd. May be locked by another application. Failed to execute (Delete)."

Comment: I need to close that project that is blocking me so I can delete it

Comment: Are you running this code in ArcMap with the MXD open? That wont work. I assumed because you just presented code you were running outside ArcMap

Comment: No, everything is closed. I have the intuition that when entering a shapefile to the project, it remains open. Therefore, what I need is to close it after having saved a copy.

Comment: A workaround may be to copy the file first using shutil.copyfile() and working out of the copy. Then os.remove() should work assuming this doesn't also create a lock, which I don't think it would.